# How to create linux user with privileges

Tags: linux

I need to install software on Linux, but it requires me to be a different user other than *root*. So I created a new user with `useradd`, created the password with `passwd`, but now I can't use simple commands in linux which I need to do the installation. i.e. I can't use `cd`, `ls`, or anything...

So my question is how do I create a new user which is able to use all of the same commands as the root user?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't use `cd`"? What happens when you try?

Comment: It says the following:
"sudo: cd: command not found"

Comment: `sudo`? Did you specify `sudo` as the user's shell?

Comment: I typed sudo cd /folder and that's the response I got

Comment: `sudo cd` doesn't make sense. `cd` is a shell builtin, moreover, it only affects the child process, so when sudo exits back to your prompt, you would still be in the old directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "sudo" in front of your commands to use a substitute user. It allows you to have admin privileges without being root (dangerous).

e.g.

sudo apt-get thePackageIWant

See [the useful instructions here](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups)

Comment: Sudo with cd still doesn't work... It says that the command is not found.

Comment: sudo doesn't work with some core stuff like cd. You need to grant privileges to the directory for the user you're logged in as, you can use chmod to do this though IIRC.