# How can I create a user account called predixmachineuser with limited privilages

Tags: predix

To install predixmachine we have to create a user account called predixmachineuser with limited privilages.Where we have to create this account?Anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to the documentation found in [Run Predix Machine as a Service](https://www.predix.io/docs/?r=764472#eqHPCWXR).

The account must be in the environment in which you are running Predix Machine.  If you are testing things out on a windows machine, then you'd [create a windows user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983294/script-to-create-windows-user-with-secret-password).  If you are testing things out on a linux machine, then you'd [create a linux user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270741/how-to-create-linux-user-with-privileges).  If you are going to run it on a microprocessor it'll depend on the environment of that microprocessor.  The specifics depend on where you are running it.

That said, it is in the docs as a production best practice.  If you are just experimenting and learning the system, you might want to check out the guide [Add Predix Machine on an Edge Device](https://www.predix.io/resources/tutorials/tutorial-details.html?tutorial_id=1742&tag=1752&journey=Setup%20Intel%20Edison%20for%20Predix(Updates%20in%20Progress)&resources=1785,1739,1742,1743) which avoids some complexity to help you build your first hello world without creating that user account at all.

Hope that helps get you started.